# How to take full-screen screenshot without menu-bar blackout bar at top?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, screen-capture

When I have an app in full-screen mode and I press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>, I get a screenshot of my entire screen, but it includes a black bar at the top that masks (blacks out) the menu bar and camera notch. I then have to open the image in my graphics-editing software to crop it out.

Is there any way to take a full-screen screenshot without this? Perhaps by altering system prefs in Terminal or by installing a third-party app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is actually baked into MacOS,

You can bring up the screenshot menu by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> and then you can select the screenshot window butten, then hover over your screen (it will turn blue) and click. The screenshot below shows how the hover menu looks and the second button is the screenshot window option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion works. I also realize now that command-shift-4 and click of my full-screen window works too.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the menu bar in the Control Center settings, then take the screenshot.

Comment: In System Prefs, Control Center, Menu Bar Only, no matter which of the four options I choose for “Automatically hide and show the menu bar”, it either does not remove the black bar, or it replaces it with the menu bar.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean that the menu bar is not actually hidden, or that the screenshot doesn't match what you see on the screen? If so, can you post a partial screenshot that shows this? Also, what macOS version?